# Laptop turns off when turned on

Tags: laptop

I have a laptop and it turns on but then shuts off before the screen displays anything. the bios screen does not even display.

I've cleared the CMOS and tried removing the battery but the only thing that does anything is if I remove the RAM, then it turns on and stays on but never goes to BIOS screen or tries to post, just the power button lights up.

The RAM is perfectly fine though, I stuck it into another laptop and all the RAM is fine nothing wrong with it. Tried some other RAM that also works but it does the same thing then, just shuts right back off again.

The previous ram is RAM it came with so I know that works with it. So what might be wrong with it? What other troubleshooting stuff can I try on this thing? Any ideas?

Comment: Could be a bad ac adapter. If the wattage or voltage is to low, some laptops will do this. Do you have another adapter on hand you can use to test?

Comment: the power adapter is perfectly fine, when I plug it in it even begins charging the battery while powered off and the charging indicator comes on the laptop. I can stick a multimeter on it and also did the battery showing them to be perfectly fine, well, the battery only holds the charge for a couple hours now but all laptops do that. this laptop is the only one that works with this ac power adapter.

Comment: The multi meter may not be able to detect an amperage deficiency. However, if you are able to power it off of only the battery and it displays the same behavior, then you are probably right and the ac adapter is fine

Comment: One thing that sometimes works is trying to boot the laptop without any accessories (ie: no hdd, no optical drive, only one stick of ram, no usb devices, etc)

Comment: or it's possible that your laptop power button is broken, causing it to be held down after it is pressed

Comment: the behavior is the same on ac and battery, the button is fine, I've resorted to pressing the actual button on the board so I don't stress the plastic button part so much, and I've removed the hard drive because I don't think it's good for it to be powering on and then off so much since I've been trying to turn on this computer for days. the laptop does not have optical drive.

Comment: Have you checked the processor heat sink?

Comment: should I remove the heatsink? the CPU is an old i7 that is soldered onto the motherboard, there is no removing the CPU. the heatsink is attached via screws, and they're all very well in, not too tight mind you, but it's firmly attached to the CPU, not loose at all. might there be a sensor issue? I don't know where the heat sensor is, I suppose it might be automatically shutting down because of that but it does not shut off if I remove all ram, the ram being known to work in it and to be good. is there something on the heatsink I should look for?

Comment: I don't think it is processor overheating issues as it hasn't run long enough. Not wanting to sound condescending, but are you sure the battery is actually charging?  Even though the charging light is on it may not actually charge up and if it isn't and there isn't enough power reaching the laptop components then it won't run

Comment: I drained the battery and it is charging